# Querying the data once and using it throughout the app like a cache

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a web app(simple jsp,servlets) with an oracle database. I have a scenario where i need

to consult a dataset (~100 rows , 4 columns) of data for a mathematical calculation. So,

instead of putting it in the database every time and reading each row every time, i was

thinking of querying the data once, and using it throughout the app like a cache. Any ideas

how to best implement this?

Comment: there are many ways, could you be more specific about how you access the database and feed the resultset into the jsp?

Comment: As @rompetroll says. The best solution for you will hugely depend on your program design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have around 400 values.Are they doubles? Then you have 1600 bytes. Why not simply read

then into an array?